# I want to install a project's dependencies with yarn in my React project, but there are various errors

Tags: c++, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

When I try to install all the dependencies of a React project with `yarn install`, I get these errors:

```
error C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
```

---

And then:

```
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31911.196) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1800) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\anything\\frontend-client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\anything\frontend-client\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
```

How could I fix it? I have tried several answers to some questions asked here on StackOverflow, but nothing works for me. :/

Comment: Use the Visual Studio Installer to get the Desktop development with C++ workload in one of the Visual Studio versions you have installed in your machine.

Comment: You got everything you need in the error message. Go to the link stated and execute all commands and install all that is said there.  sometimes installing `windows-build-tools` helps a lot

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero I have already done so. In fact, I have Visual Studio Community 2022 installed and installed that same workload on it. Then I ran "yarn install" again and it still gives me the same error.

However, I noticed that from Visual Studio Installer I have Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 with a Visual C++ Build Tools package that I can install to it.  Also, the command "npm config msvs_version" returns 2017 to me. I'll give it a try and see how it goes.